# Superradiant scattering in ergosphere?

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, gravitational-lensing

In a black hole there is a region of space where only energy can escape, the ergosphere. I read superradiant scattering can allow lights to gain energy much like gravity assist, what is the different in gravitational lensing where light slows down and get bended and this superradiant scattering?

Answer (score 1):

In gravitational lensing, all geodesics in spacetime bend close to a mass, so that light's "straight" path through space curves. In superradiant scattering, a fraction of the incoming mass falls into the black hole, causing the black hole to transfer some of its angular momentum to the remaining mass. (Yes, black holes spin. Think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) or even [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric) instead of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric).) This surviving mass continues to move through the distorted spacetime around the black hole, subject to not so much gravitational lensing as [frame dragging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging).

What source did you read? Although [Kurzgesagt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulCdoCfw-bY) claims light is a candidate, it is not; photons have no rest mass, whereas the wave used for this process needs to be [a massive boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_bomb).